# Polymer app-router Cordova support

Tags: cordova, routes, polymer

everything work in Chrome but when I export it to Android using Cordova nothing seems to appear.

Only white screen is there.

```
<body unresolved fullbleed>

 <app-router>
  <app-route path="/" import="/elements/kwikblood-fblogin.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/panel" import="/elements/kwikblood-panel.html"></app-route>
 </app-router>

 <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is basically what I've done

Comment: Hi, to anyone facing the same problem, here is please refer this thread https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router/issues/59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came down to different platforms using different folder structures following this pattern `file://**/www/index.html`.

You can solve it by creating 2 routes for the main page like this.

```html
<app-router>
  <app-route path="/" import="pages/home-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/**/www/index.html" import="pages/home-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="*" import="pages/not-found.html"></app-route>
</app-router>
```

https://erikringsmuth.github.io/app-router/#/notes#cordova

Answer (score 0):

As he mentioned in the comments, this happens because of file path munging in cordova.

I am using a different router, and it works under cordova: https://github.com/atotic/excess-router